# Give permission to folder only to root and owner in BASH

Tags: bash, permissions, chmod

I am looking for a confirmation. I still do not understand chmod command.

What I want is to give permissions to root and owner to a folder in a supercomputer cluster.

My first approach would be:   **chmod -R 750**

**Is that correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, root has access to literally anything so there is no need for explicit permissions to give root access to something (there are exceptions like when it comes to certain NFS options).

The question then becomes: what user and group own the directory?  If the user and the user's group own the directory, then something like `750` is fine.  If a different user and/or group owns the directory, then the permissions need to change.

Comment: Thank you, if possible, can you help me out to understand what each number and its position means?

Comment: @Another.Chemist check this pic https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F2.bp.blogspot.com%2F-V2eWUJugBJ0%2FUi4Y1TJ45aI%2FAAAAAAAAAzQ%2Fgwxcb-GlTGA%2Fs1600%2Fchmod4.png&f=1&nofb=1

Comment: [There are far better explanations available](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/) than anything I could write in a comment.